# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 'CIAttributeTypeRectangle.'

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I am learning how to program and I am experimenting with the camera. I've been trying to apply a `CICrop` filter to an image, but in crashes each time. Here is the code:

```
let Rectangle = CIVector(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y, z: view.bounds.height, w: view.bounds.width)

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)

filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(Rectangle, forKey: kCIAttributeTypeRectangle)

let originalOrientation: UIImageOrientation = imageView.image!.imageOrientation
let originalScale = imageView.image!.scale

let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: inputImage.extent())

imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage, scale: originalScale, orientation: originalOrientation)
```

It constantly crashes on this line: `filter.setValue(Rectangle, forKey: kCIAttributeTypeRectangle)`

Can somebody help me with whats going on? Also, please provide code in the answer because, like I said before, I'm still trying to learn. Thank you!

Comment: Is inputImage an IBOutlet?

Comment: No, it's role is to make the UIImage a CIImage so i can apply a CIFilter to it

Answer (score 0):

The "not key value coding-compliant" error is often b/c you have an outlet that is no longer attached to your view controller.  Right click on your imageView in the storyboard and see if you have any referencing outlets that are outdated (i.e., removed from your code but not removed from the storyboard object).

Comment: I already checked that, there are no outdated outlets, but thanks!